# addSubview disrupts animation in swift

Tags: swift, animation, asynchronous, subview

Method to call animation

```
    for button in self.exploreButtonsArray {
        button.exploreButtonExitAnimation()
    }

    setupDrinkExploreButtons()
```

Code for animation:

```
func exploreButtonExitAnimation() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(random, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.center.x -= 400
        }, completion: {(value: Bool) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
    })

}
```

The `setupDrinkExploreButtons()` method calls on `.addSubview(exploreButton)` and adds some buttons to a container. Are my animations messing up because these actions are being performed asynchronously?

[image: This is the very first view before any animation]

[image: How the view looks without calling setupDrinkExploreButtons()]

[image: What it looks like when calling setupDrinkExploreButtons()]

1st image: This is the very first view before any animation

2nd image: How the view looks without calling setupDrinkExploreButtons(). All the buttons move gracefully to the left.

3rd image: What it looks like when calling setupDrinkExploreButtons()

In the 3rd image you can see how the buttons don't disappear but instead they seem to "animate in" to fit the view. Instead of moving to the left 400 units like they're supposed to, it seems like they suddenly appear 400 units to the right and then move to the left to fit their original position???

Comment: you may want to check the values of the "random" to see that they are in the appropriate range value.

Comment: @Dasem The problem with the animation isn't that the speed is random. I've taken a few screenshots to demonstrate how the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you're using the same references to the old an new views in self.exploreButtonsArray or emptying the array when you create the new views. If you want to post your code surrounding this then I can take a look.

However, I have a few suggestions:

First, this is a somewhat unreliable way to do your animations. You will be creating a dozen animation blocks and depending on the timing, they may start and end at slightly different times. This may or may not be noticeable, but it's a bad habit to get into and is less efficient. To avoid this issue, you could do something like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: random, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    for button in self.exploreButtonsArray {
        // BTW this is also unreliable, I would strongly suggest using definite values when animating
        button.center.x -= 400
    }
}, completion: { (finished) in
    for button in self.exploreButtonsArray {
        button.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```

Second, If you're grouping views together like this, it would be much better to put them all in a view, then animate that view instead. This is more efficient for both performance and simpler when coding.

Third, it seems like you're trying to do some pretty simple paging. If you're just having fun and want to implement it yourself, go for it! If not, you probably want to use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) or [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html). I guarantee it will mean fewer headaches :)